# Android 4.3 Virtual Device CPU/ABI - No system images installed (eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm trying to set up a new device, but I can not continue with the process.
I think it's because the target version is 4.3.
[image]

I know I need to download it from ***Android SDK manager***.
But as you can see it has been installed
[image]

Comment: did you restart eclipse after you installed the image? do you have Android Studio installed as well?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Reinstall the ARM EABI v7a system Image and Intel x86 Atom System Image again
restart the eclipse
I think it will work

Comment: It workend for me only after downloading both system images (ARM and X86)

Answer (score 8):

You Just **close the ADT** and **open it**.. it will surely work. it's work for me.

And check the **Target as Android 4.4 - API level 19..**

Answer (score 1):

What I have done is:

I'll Android SDK Manager. I have installed the following points; 
Platform SDK. 
ARM EABI V7A System Image

For the API you need.

close eclipse

After I go to Windows Explorer. A folder: ..\sdk\system-images 
And entered into the System image that you use, I can inside a folder called "default" and 
in "armeabi-v7a" only have to cut and move the last folder where the default and 
then delete default.

open eclipse

This works.

Answer (score 0):

open your sdk manager and install 
- ARM EABI v7a System Image
- Intel x86 Atom System Image
for each API Level.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you earn sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. If you have a related but different question, ask a new question referencing this one if it will help provide context.