# In eclipse I a getting the API level 20 .I want ot use lower versions of API

Tags: android, eclipse

How to change API level. when selecting this API level it shows no CPU/ABi available and also I am not able to add text fields it throws an exception.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnhCq.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vNm1.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse go to manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="int" />
```

In android studio: go to your app `Gradle` there you can find the `minSdkVersion`. Lower it to the version you needed.

```
android {
    ....
    defaultConfig {
        ....
        minSdkVersion 17
        ....
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not able find any option like gradle..could yu help me to find it

Comment: @R.Manjula Check your project root folder `AppFolder/app/build.gradle`

Comment: There is no option like this I am using eclipse juno

Comment: I changed the version in maifest file but i am getting the same error..The only target available to me is android 4.4 W when creating android virtual device

Answer (score 0):

- Quick Fix: Uncheck installed checkbox to see other downloads and try to refresh android sdk manager, restart it or restart the computer. API 19 worked fine for me before I moved to android studio.
- I'm not sure if API 20 is supported in eclipse, I recommend Android Studio for android development. Anyway, if you have an old PC that does not meet android studio minimum requirement, download IntelliJ IDEA https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/, it's a bit lighter and free and require 1 GB of RAM (But 1 GB is very bad, you need at least 2 GB without running android emulator). However, if you still want to work with eclipse I think you need API 19 you have to download it manually from the web and move it to android SDK location. Or you can install android studio to download SDK without using it.
- Newer APIs are way better, they have more libraries that supports both old and new android versions. It's really worth upgrading to Android Studio.
- For the CPU/ABi error check this post [Android 4.3 Virtual Device CPU/ABI - No system images installed (eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600974/android-4-3-virtual-device-cpu-abi-no-system-images-installed-eclipse)

Comment: The college systems doesn't support android studio we want to use eclipse only.So how to download the API 19 from which website and how to install it.

Comment: If the SDK manager still not showing other than API 20 try installing android studio and download the api from it to use it in eclipse. Can you show what type of error you get with textfield. I'm not sure if API 20 is supported or not, I know android marshmallow doesn't work in eclipse ADT.

Comment: OKkk got it uncheck installed checkbox in android sdk manager to see other APIs

Comment: I downloaded the API zip file but i am confused , where and how to add it so that I can create AVD .

Comment: look in android studio sdk path in top (your pic), put it  inside that folder inside platform folder

Comment: extract the zip there it should be named android-19

Comment: To use android emulator you need to download android system-image (uncheck installed first to see all downloads)

Comment: Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V This is the error I am getting.

Comment: When I uncheck the installed checkbok I didn't find anything it is blank

Comment: Tried to restart? could be something wrong with the connection maybe.. you said you downloaded a zip file did you put it where i told you?

Comment: I don't know maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341683/android-sdk-manager-is-not-showing-all-packages

Comment: Yes I pasted inside platform folder but i am getting only API 20

Comment: do you have inside the extracted folder folders like (data, templates, skins) or android.jar file ?

Comment: Yes..but again same error i am getting only API level 20

Comment: idk, you can ask your instructor at college, if he uses eclipse he should have a fix for you, but seriously eclipse ADT is outdated it is common to find those bugs even with java I use JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA. Maybe you can convince your instructor to let you use android studio, anyway I hope you find a solution.